# Password and re-enter password validation with Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am migrating to Polymer 1.0 from Polymer 0.5 and I'm not able to do a simple validation -  the classic scenario of a password and a re-enter password field.

With Polymer 0.5 I had:

```
<paper-input-decorator id="passwordDecId" label="New password (8 caratteri almeno)" floatingLabel error="campo obbligatorio!">
    <input id="passwordId" onchange="validatePassword()" is="core-input" type="password" name="password" required pattern=".{8,32}">
</paper-input-decorator>
<paper-input-decorator id="reenterPasswordDecId" label="Re-enter password (8 caratteri almeno)" floatingLabel error="campo obbligatorio!">
    <input id="reenterPasswordId" onchange="validatePassword()" is="core-input" type="password" name="reenterPassword" required pattern=".{8,32}">
</paper-input-decorator>
```

and the validatePassword function was:

```
function validatePassword() {
    var passwordDecorator = document.getElementById('passwordDecId');
    var passwordInput = document.getElementById('passwordId');
    var reenterPasswordDecorator = document.getElementById('reenterPasswordDecId');
    var reenterPasswordInput = document.getElementById('reenterPasswordId');
    var pass2 = reenterPasswordInput.value;
    var pass1 = passwordInput.value;

    if (pass1 != pass2) {
        reenterPasswordInput.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
    } else {
        // empty string means no validation error
        reenterPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('');
    }

    passwordDecorator.isInvalid = !passwordInput.validity.valid;
    reenterPasswordDecorator.isInvalid = !reenterPasswordInput.validity.valid;
}
```

and it worked, but now, after having migrated to Polymer 1.0, I'm not using paper-input-decorator anymore and so I would like to do everything with only paper-input:

```
<paper-input id="passwordId" onchange="validatePassword()" name="password" type="text" label="New password" auto-validate required pattern=".{1,32}" error-message="1 caratteri almeno"></paper-input>

<paper-input id="reenterPasswordId" onchange="validatePassword()" name="reenterPassword" type="text" label="Re-enter password" auto-validate required pattern=".{1,32}" error-message="1 caratteri almeno"></paper-input>
```

I don't know how to change the `validatePassword` function to show an error when the length of the two passwords are greater than 1 character **but the values are different** and when user presses either the submit button or when the focus of the inputs is lost.

Comment: not sure if it's still actual, but you can implement custom validator, see here how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955091/how-to-add-custom-validator-to-paper-input

Answer (score 3):

here some example for how to validated match password using polymer 1.0

```
<paper-input label="Password" required value="{{pass::input}}" id="checkPassword"></paper-input>
<paper-input label="Re-type Password" required value="{{repass::input}}" on-change="passmatch" id="checkPassword"></paper-input>
```

and add *passmatch* function

```
passmatch: function(e){
      var password = encodeURIComponent(this.pass);
      var confirmPassword = encodeURIComponent(this.repass);
      if(password != confirmPassword){
        // do something
      }
    }
```