# how to use a custom validator for 2 different paper-inputs

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to have two elements

```
<validation-element idx="1"></validation-element>
<validation-element idx="2"></validation-element>
```

where both of them contain paper-input with a custom validation.

```
<custom-validator validator-name="validator" idx="[[idx]]"></custom-validator>
<paper-input type="text" auto-validate validator='validator'></paper-input>
```

in validate function I log out `idx`:

```
validate: function(val) {
  console.log('idx',this.idx, 'val',val);
  return true;
}
```

Here is [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLzCAN) of what I have

Problem is that in console I see `idx=2` for both elements BUT they are use separate validators.

Why do I see the same `idx` in different elements?

How to make separate validators for 2 elements?

Comment: A similar question has been asked before. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955091/how-to-add-custom-validator-to-paper-input).

Comment: here we are dealing with a generic way to have custom validator...

Comment: Having a look at the plunk that was posted, I noticed it was actually forked from my plunk in that other question. :) Anyway, I think it's still good to have a link to the other question just for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IronValidatorBehavior` is implemented using `iron-meta`. The `validator-name` is the key used to register the validator, so that, when you create the second instance, it just replace the first one!

[EDIT] As discussed, using computed property is the way to go, but you also have to add an observer to the validatorName in the custom-validator, so that we can create a new `iron-meta` with proper key!
See: http://plnkr.co/edit/mLDU20?p=preview

Comment: ok, so what is the good way of registering different validators? make computed property and bind `validator-name` using it?

Comment: wait a sec, I am updating your plunk! :)

Comment: unfoturnately that approach doesn't work. see http://plnkr.co/edit/WyZhbR
validator never called if using compute parameter...

Comment: yep, because the ready function of the custom-validator is called too early... and the 'iron-meta' is created there...

Comment: defering the iron-meta creation in the attached function would make it functional

Comment: but I dont use iron-meta explicitly so don't understand how can I possibly  deffer it. Could you provide an example?